# LaTeX Symbol for a not related to b

Tags: notation, relations

Typically you have a relation `R` like this --> `aRb`. However, I am trying to find the symbol "opposite" of `R`, to say `a` is not related to `b`. It looks like `R`, but with a diagonal line through it. What is the LaTeX command for this symbol?

Comment: you can try here to write it... if it exists it will appear: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Use \not in front of any relation symbol and latex will negate it for you. Example $\not \in$ $\not \subset$ $\not \sim$ $\not \geq$

Comment: I would write $(a,b)\notin R$ because this notation is completely standard and clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this? $a \not\mathrel{R} b$

If so, type: \$a \not \mathrel{R} b\$.

You didn't mention this, but if you also prefer using the notation $a \sim b$, where $\sim$ is the relation, then $a \nsim b$ is typed as \$a \nsim b\$.

Comment: You're welcome.

By the way, you should visit https://tex.stackexchange.com/ rather than this site. It'll have more of what you're looking for.